# How to remove year from datetime to plot years on top of each other

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to compare 10 years of data. I would like to remove the 'year' from the datetime, so I can plot each January on top of each other.

I've tried the following

```
df_data = pd.read_csv("P11-B2.csv", skiprows=[i for i in range(1,35)], usecols=[1,2,4])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Datetime', 'FH'])

df1 = pd.to_datetime(df_data['YYYYMMDD'], format='%Y%m%d')

df2 = df_data['   HH'].astype('timedelta64[h]')
df['Datetime'] = df1 + df2
df['FH'] = pd.to_numeric(df_data['   FH'], errors ='coerce')
del df1
del df2
del df_data

df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Datetime']).month
df100 = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m')
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Datetime']).day
df101 = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%d')
df['hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Datetime']).hour
df102 = df['hour'].astype('timedelta64[h]')
df['year'] = 1900
df104 = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y')

#df['DATE'] = df104 + df100 + df101 + df102
df['DATE'] = df['year'] + df['month'] + df['day'] + df['hour']
```

Though this returns an integer.

Is there a different way to only remove the year and keep the `%m%d%H` format?
Or is there a simple way to override the x-axis and use the integer?

[This is what i would like to plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAkUy.png)

I want to make a plot for each month, showing different lines for each year.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you would like to get as a result?

Comment: I have added a figure